# Why my validation URL image in CodeIgniter 4 It is taking too long?

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, curl, url

I have a project in CodeIgniter 4, I need to validate url to display in a [datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/index), I make the request with ajax, it's working but taking too long...

In this example the limit to show only **50** rows and it is taking 2.4 minutes...
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9EHI.png)

I'm using [curl](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/curlrequest.html) + datatables, my code below:

```
<?php 
    ... 

    // Return result array of query 
    foreach ($this->query->datatables() as $row) {

        $images = '<div style="width: 70px; height: 40px;"><ul class="list-inline">';

        // More 3 loop, max 3 images for row
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) { 

            // Valid URL with CURL
            $url_image = 'www.examples.com/images/'. $row->name . $i .'.jpg';
            $response = $this->curl->request('GET', $url_image, [
                'connect_timeout' => 0,
                'http_errors' => false
            ]);

            // Increment images, if success
            if ($response->getStatusCode() == 200){
                $images .= '
                <li class="list-inline-item">
                    <img style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" class="table-avatar" src="'.$url_image.'">
                </li>
                ';
            }
        }

        $images .= '</ul></div>';


        // Result in array
        $data[] = array(
            $images
        );
    }
    
    ...
?>
```

I tried use `file_exists` but not working... what can i do to improve?

Thank you all, and sorry for the english mistakes.

Comment: Given that you are using cURL in a loop for every image it is not likely that you'll be able to speed it up much. How long things takes depends almost entirely on how quickly the host you are retrieving the images from responds and, unless it your host, probably not something you can control/change.

Comment: Maybe this doesn't need to happen on every single page load? You could _cache_ the results of those checks on your end for a while ...

Comment: How could I validate these URLs quickly?

Comment: Unfortunately verification is required on every load page... @CBroe

Comment: Maybe do it on the client side instead? Output _all_ the images, and add an `error` handler to them - so that when the request made by the client fails, you can then hide that particular image afterwards ...?

Comment: Would you have any example?

Comment: The solution I found was to access the images via FTP, thank for all.